# Bootstrap: Spacing in a navbar under django

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to do a navbar in Bootstrap:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="navbar-text">
                        {{ object }}
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li class="navbar-text">
                        {{ object2 }}
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li class="navbar-text">
                        {{ object3 }}
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li class="navbar-text">
                        {{ object4 }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when it renders, it pushes all the objects up against each other in the navbar. How do I enforce spacing between them?

Comment: Maybe add padding to `.navbar-text` elements?

Comment: can you show the test page you are working on , will be easier for us to help

Comment: Generally the bootstrap navbar is ready to go solution and if its not rendering correctly then there is some other styling affecting it

Comment: Thanks, EP! That did the trick. Any idea how to create an indentation, to move the objects over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
color: #777777;
float: none;
padding: 10px 15px;/* this the one which enforces space between each link*/
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

Please check the above code I gave ya .. the bootstrap css must be having these lines check them to see if they are altered .

Or you can just create a new stylesheet include it after all the bootstrap css files and override any other css rule which is affecting the same .

Regarding indentation

```
    .navbar .nav > li > a:hover
     {
    text-indent:100px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Shail! Do you have anything about my indentation question?

Comment: If you can show me a test page I can surely help , more precisely .

Comment: All the relevant information should be in there. The rest of it is just an HTML page that's being plugged in. I just want to know how to indent, generally.

Comment: text-indent is a property can be used for the indentation purpose. Added  an example above.. check

Comment: You are welcome! .. if you get stuck somewhere . You can email me as well .